# Is there any way to stop and start video calling like audio features in opentok.js

Tags: javascript, c#, opentok

Is there any way to stop and start video calling like audio features in **opentok.js**

When Publisher and subscriber is on video call then user can off camera and again user can On camera.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle camera on/off while video call.
Here is example.

```
​<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <body>
 <div id='myPublisherDiv'></div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Video</button>
 <script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script charset="utf-8">
 var publisher;
 var apiKey = 'apikey';
 var sessionId = 'session id'; 
 var token = 'token';
 var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId)
 .on('streamCreated', function(event) {
 session.subscribe(event.stream);
 })
 .connect(token, function(error) {
 var pubOptions = {publishAudio:true, publishVideo:true};
 publisher = OT.initPublisher(myPublisherDiv, pubOptions);
 session.publish(publisher);
 });
 var enableVideo=true;
 function myFunction() {
 if(enableVideo)
 {
 publisher.publishVideo(false);
 enableVideo=false;
 } else
 {
 publisher.publishVideo(true);
 enableVideo=true;
 }
 }
```